# Drupal hash salt / private key is changing?

Tags: tokens

I've created a token that I store in database, here is how I create my token :

```
$token = drupal_hmac_base64($pid . " " . $order_id . " " . $solde, drupal_get_private_key() . drupal_get_hash_salt());
```

And then when a user go to my url that looks like that :

```
https://mycustomwebsite.com/order_id/token
```

With the token and another value : `order_id`, I get the line in my database with the `order_id` and then I create a new token :

```
$new_token = drupal_hmac_base64($pid . " " . $order->order_id . " " . $solde, drupal_get_private_key() . drupal_get_hash_salt());
```

I compare these two tokens just for a verification to grant the access or not.

This works fine but couple days after when I try to go on a link the access doesn't work anymore. When I look at the `new_token` generated for verification it's not the same !
But the value used to make this token (`pid`, `order_id` and `solde`) are the same, so here is why I ask my question.

Does the `drupal_get_hash_salt()` or `drupal_get_private_key()` can return different values in the time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`drupal_get_hash_salt()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_hash_salt/7.x) is either:

- a manually-entered value stored in your `settings.php`
- ...or (by default) a hash of your serialized-DB config

[`drupal_get_private_key()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_private_key/7.x) is either:

- a stored variable called `drupal_private_key` if it's set
- ...or (by default) randomly generated bytes (that are saved to `drupal_private_key` after generation)

So, either one can change their value if:

- You changed your DB config (if `$drupal_hash_salt` isn't manually set in `settings.php`).
- You've lost/removed `drupal_private_key` from the `variable` DB table.